# Google Apps Scripts, onEdit function wont gets no value on edited range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm making a task manager in Google Sheets that when a task is created it sends the task that was just made to a target  Sheet, I was able to get it to send the data just fine to the target sheet but my problem lies with what i wanted to do with that edit made on the target sheet. On the target sheet I want it to grab that info that was just inputted and place it in the next available row, but when I test my code It doesn't wanna work correctly.

My Code(for the target sheet):

```
function onEdit (e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetIdHere'); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var openRow = 0;  
  for (var i =4;i < sheetRows;i++) {
  var currentValue = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    if (currentValue == "") {
    openRow = i;
      break;

    }
  }
  var lastEdit = sheet.getRange(1000, 2, 1, 3);
  var lastEditValues = lastEdit.getValues();
   var openRange = sheet.getRange(openRow, 2, 1, 3);
  var openA1 = openRange.getA1Notation();
  sheet.getRange(openA1).setValues(lastEditValues);
}
```

So far from my tests, the `for` loop to find the next available row is working fine because when I make another change on the sheet afterward it will grab the edited information fine and input it into the next row, but on the initial `onEdit` fire it will just grab the values from the previous test at row 1000 and put it into the next row instead of the new values.
I feel like there is a mistiming perhaps on when it grabs the values because if I clear the sheets and send a new task nothing appears on the next available row but I might be mistaken on that feeling.

Comment: You can use the `appendRow()` function on your sheet in order to add the data to the next available row (end of your sheet).

Comment: @Casper Thank You, that shortens my code by a bunch but my problem still persists.

Comment: The description of what you're trying to do is kind of confusing to me. You have a form (I presume) that allows users to create rows on a sheet. When a new row is added, you want the script to duplicate the row to the next available (so most likely the next) row? From what I understand you have this part working, but I'm not sure whether you want this to happen again when you make a manual edit or not as the second part of your description is unclear. What's happening and what should happen?

Comment: @Casper Sorry for the bad description. A better description is that I have 2 sheets, when I make an edit on the first sheet it takes the info from the edit and posts it onto the second sheet, this works fine. The problem lies in getting the info to post to the next available row. How I went about fixing this problem was by putting the info from the the first form into the second form then on the second sheet in an `onEdit` function I take the info, find the next available row and input it, but it doesn't work. I think what made my question confusing was explaining what i've tried already